# Set Default selection in Django MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, html, django, multiple-select

I have a MultipleChoiceField  set in my forms.py and was wondering how to have a default option highlighted when the user opens the form.

**forms.py**

```
def getCompReqNum():
    listCompNum = []

    all_reqs = Requisition.objects.distinct()
    for i in all_reqs:
        ....
        ....
    return tuple(listCompNum)

class CandidateForm(ModelForm)
...
    self.fields['req'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = getCompReqNum(), label = '* Requisition(s)')
    self.fields['req'].initial = "some default option"
...
widgets = {
'req_id'    : SelectMultiple()
 }
```

**models.py**

```
class Candidate(models.Model)
...
   req = models.ManyToManyField(Requisition, blank = True)
....
```

The self.fields['field_name'].initial does not seem to be setting a default value for me. Is there another option to set so that when the form is loaded a default option is already highlighted on the form? Screenshot below of what I want to accomplish.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3MC7.png)

**HTML Inspection**

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="id_req" name="req">
    <option value="56565">11-22 (sw2) (56565) </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Setting `self.fields['req'].initial` should work for unbound forms. You'll have to add more information for us to see why it isn't working.

Comment: @Alasdair the field is calling getCompReqNum() which is pulling data from the database and populating the form with the pulled information. Does this mean that the form is no longer considered unbound?

Comment: Provide the body of  the `getCompReqNum()`, is it returning `queryset`? Maybe you just need to change the default `queryset` and nothing more and you will be good to go. `self.fields['req'].queryset = getCompReqNum()`

Comment: @Todor I have the function returning a tuple. (Added Code)

Comment: Try to set up a list the the ids you want preselected. `self.fields['req'].initial = [id1, id2,...]` but i dont think you need to redefine the whole field, because m2m fields evaluates to a  `ModelMultipleChoiceField` by default.

Comment: @Todor I used `self.fields['req'].initial = ['56565']` which did nothing. I even tried `self.fields['req'].initial = ['56565', '12345']` which also did nothing but it didn't throw and error either, which I though was weird. I inspected the element in HTML and added it above.

Comment: Try with integer instead of string